# replace row value in COL2 by NA where other COL3 value is NA in R

Tags: r, dplyr

Hello I have a dataframe such as :

```
COL1 COL2 COL3
A    12   32
B    NA   NA
C    NA   NA
D    0    NA
E    21   90
F    0    NA
```

and I would like to replace all `COL2` values by `NA` where `COL3` value is `NA`

Here I should get

```
   COL1 COL2 COL3
    A    12   32
    B    NA   NA
    C    NA   NA
    D    NA   NA
    E    21   90
    F    NA   NA
```

So far I tried :

```
df$COL2[is.na(df$COL3)] <- NA
```

but it does not seem to work

Comment: You're code works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# your data
COL1 <- c("A","B","C","D","E","F")
COL2 <- c(12, NA, NA, 0, 21, 0)
COL3 <- c(32, NA, NA, NA, 90, NA)

# create df
df <- cbind.data.frame(COL1, COL2, COL3)

# replacing COL2 with NA when COL3 = NA
df$COL2 <- ifelse(is.na(df$COL3), df$COL3, df$COL2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% mutate(COL2 = ifelse(is.na(COl3), NA, COL2))
```